# Aurora Serverless on GA version permit connections from internet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

I know that Aurora serverless version, on the preview, has the following restrictions: 
There isn't enable for connection from internet. Only is possible connections from the same VPC in which is our Aurora cluster.

Now, Aurora serverless is on general availability, so I am wondering if this restriction exists nowadays.

Someone have had success exposing the aurora serverless cluster to internet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. According to their forums, that feature is still on their to-do list.

Source:https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=863705#863705

Comment: Could this be achieved via a public proxy of some sort, maybe a TCP-level proxy like HAProxy or Traefik?