# Aurora serverless not connecting from CLI and mysql workbrench

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, aws-serverless

I make a Aurora serverless cluster and trying to connect it from command line using command

```
mysql --user=mightycpa --password -h serverless.cluster-xxxxxx
```

but it can't connect and gives an error

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server
```

I tried with mysql workbench also but not works.
I checked VPC group and security groups and give it accessible form anywhere.

For testing I create Aurora Rds with serverless with same VPC and security groups and it connects fine.

Can we connect severless from local CLI or not? if yes then any change needed?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52194191/aurora-serverless-on-ga-version-permit-connections-from-internet. The tutorial https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/configure-connect-serverless-mysql-database-aurora/ gets you halfway there, but I don't know how to get the created EC2 instance to behave as a proxy for the database yet.

Answer (score 1):

We can't connect it from ssh or using local machine etc.
For it we need to use `Cloud9` and list all databases there